# Create multiple active records with variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, activerecord, bulkinsert, bulk

I have an option to create users one by one with their names and email addresses as parameters:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Add User') %>
<h1>Add User</h1>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/user_error_messages' %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control'%>

  <%= f.submit "Add User", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

What I wish to do is to have an option to create multiple users at a time. It should be a text area where you can enter names of users to be added. It should then parse the names and add "@domain.com" to create email addresses, as well, e.g. there's a Test Name, it should create a test.name@domain.com email address so that each user from bulk has a name and email address. There's no question in this part, just to be on the same page.

I have read a few threads on how to create multiple active records in rails, however, I am not sure how to pass the variables here and to make bulk create option work.

If any additional details are required, please do let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Parameters are passed from your view to your controller in the `params` hash.

Comment: @steveklein I have `def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
end` in my users_controller for single users' creations. However, I can't use this or similar for multiple entries or at least I can't understand how this can be done. If you could elaborate that would be great

Comment: OK I posted as an answer as it was getting a little involved for a comment.  Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: @steveklein thank you, I'm on the right way now I think. I will post an update later, thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help Denis.  Please accept answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in your controller. First do what steve klein says, then you can do the following.
For example if you want to use a text field to enter the new user names you can do something like in your form:

```
<%= f.label :user_names %>
<%= f.text_field :user_names_string, class: 'form-control' %>
```

And then access :user_names_string in your controller like this:

```
user_names_string = params[:user_names_string]
user_names = user_names_string.split(',').map(&:strip)
user_names.each do |user_name|
  User.create(name: user_name, email: user_name + "@domain.com")
end
```

You could move some of this to the model, like the "@domain" part.
You could also make new fields in your form per user, but this may get you on the right track.

Comment: thank you, I think this should help! I will try it and post later

Comment: here's what I now have in my controller:
`def create
@user = User.new(user_params)
if @user.save
flash[:info] = "User added!"
redirect_to users_path
else
render 'new'
end
end

def bulk
user_names_string = params[:user_names_string]
user_names = user_names_string.split(',').map(&:strip)
user_names.each do |user_name|
User.create(name: user_name, email: user_name + "@domain.com")
end
end

def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :user_names, :user_names_string)
end
end` but it will not split the string since its nil, also "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty"

Comment: Use https://gist.github.com/ to make and link code, so I can read it better... But you should put it inside your create (and maybe update) action, not make it a separate action.

Comment: yes, that's what I really thought, though I need both of the options - create one by one and a bulk one. I think, I should somehow join create and bulk methods to get a separate working one

Comment: Look at this: https://gist.github.com/WvanLelyveld/d229ff7a6d9297f7b54e
You should still change it a bit to only create them when everything is valid, but this should get you going. Make sure to know how to use 'pry' or 'byebug' so you can see the values of your methods in your controllers.

Comment: thank you very much, though for some reason it is not passing the parameters to the name: and email: it is processing the request until the moment of creation itself, so it just stops with an invalid POST request. I have tried some options(a lot of them, frankly) one of them is adding `User.create(user_params[name: user_name, email: user_name + "@domain.com"])` it still reverts the responses which you can find here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6fbd03c0de666b6fa343 . I will try to experiment more with the code with a help of a friend, though at this time I am in the deadlock. again thanks

Comment: You should just post to the controller with "/", not to " bulk". In my example the create action calls the bulk method.

Comment: thanks, guys! I have done this in a bit different way, though your solutions made it

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you will need to:

1. Either use an existing model attribute or create a new one (`attr_accessor`) to associate with a `text_area` field in your view.
2. Add that attribute to your permitted `user_params`.

Once you do that, this new attribute will be populated from your view and available in your controller for processing.  You will just need to break into user names, format as desired and create new users in a loop.